# Hug features with KNN

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue with the following code. In particular, the problem after splitting the data and feeding it into the KNN.

```
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier


image_paths=[] #List to store path of all images
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('MICC-F220'):
    for filename in filenames:
        image_paths.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))


original_images=[]
tampered_images=[]

for path in image_paths:
    if 'tamp' in path:              
        tampered_images.append(path)
    else:
        original_images.append(path)
tampered_images.sort()
original_images.sort()
print(len(original_images),len(tampered_images))


data= []
labels = []
from skimage.feature import hog
from PIL import Image

# compute HOG features and label them:
for file in original_images: 
    img = Image.open(file) # open the file
    gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel i.e. RGB to grayscale
    fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True)
    data.append(fd)
    labels.append(0)

for file in tampered_images: 
    img = Image.open(file) 
    gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel i.e. RGB to grayscale
    fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True)
    data.append(fd)
    labels.append(1)


le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)

trainData, testData, trainLabels, testLabels = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42) 

print(" Training KKN classifier...")
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels)
#%% Evaluate the classifier
print(" Evaluating classifier on test data ...")
predictions = model.predict(testData)
print(classification_report(testLabels, predictions))`
```

I tried something like `data = np.array(data)` but it didn't help.
Also, I tried to reshape the input array (`reshape(1,-1)`) but this didn't solve the issue either.

The error I'm getting is:
`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you please add the error you get and an excerpt of the data you are using?

Comment: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it is better if you add it to the question :)

Comment: how can i add to question

Comment: You can edit the question: look at the bottom of it